# Compounding interest calculator in a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a calculator that calculates simple interest and compounding interest. All good, with the simple interest, but I can't seem to be able to solve the problem with the compounding interest, using a loop. I need a loop, because pushing the data into an array to use it in a chart later.

I have the formula from here: https://www.moneysmart.gov.au/managing-your-money/saving/compound-interest

I am using this as reference: https://www.bankrate.com/calculators/retirement/roi-calculator.aspx

The code is in work here: http://www.course0001.com/fiverr/iddqd
I have this so far(updated):

```
// Inputs from user:

// Initial deposit (starting balance)
// Number of years
// Interest
// Frequent Deposit amount
// Deposit and compound frequency (monthly, weekly, yearly)

// Calculations
var investedCapitalArray = [];
var simpleInterestArray = [];
var compoundInterestArray = [];
var compoundPrincipal = 0;
var years = [];
var accumulatedInvestment;

function calculate() {
    years = [];
    let interest = rateNumeric.getNumber() / 100; // annual interest rate
    let additionalDeposit = additionalNumeric.getNumber(); // Regular deposit
    let frequency = freqInput.value; // Frequency of regular deposit
    let initialDeposit = initialNumeric.getNumber();
    let taxRate = taxNumeric.getNumber();

    // Invested captal amount first year
    investedCapitalArray = [];
    investedCapitalArray.push(initialDeposit + (frequency * additionalDeposit));

    // simple interest first year
    simpleInterestArray = [];
    simpleInterestArray.push((investedCapitalArray[0]  * ( (interest) / 100)) * (1 - taxRate));

    // compund interest first year
    compoundInterestArray = [];
    let firstYearInvestment = investedCapitalArray[0]; // First deposit + regular deposits in first year

    for (let i = 1 ; i < yearsInput.value ; i++) {
        // Invested capital over the years (correct results)
        investedCapitalArray.push( (investedCapitalArray[i-1]) +
            (frequency * additionalDeposit) );

        // simple interest over the years (correct results)
        simpleInterestArray.push( simpleInterestArray[i-1] +
            ((firstYearInvestment + 
            ((frequency) * additionalDeposit) * i ) * interest) );

        // compound interest over the years (incorrect results)  
        compoundInterestArray.push( investedCapitalArray[i-1] * 
            Math.pow(1 + interest / 100, i) -  initialDeposit);

        years.push('Year' +i);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the inputs, after thoroughly researching the compounding interest topic, I wrote an algorithm that works perfectly. It's actually quite simple.

My algorithm is based on this explanation:
"What Is Compound Interest? Compound interest (or compounding interest) is interest calculated on the initial principal, which also includes all of the accumulated interest of previous periods of a deposit or loan."

Therefore it works like this in a loop:

compoundInterest += (((simpleInterestArray[i - 1] + compoundInterest) * (interest));

Full code below.

```
    for (let i = 1; i < yearsInput.value; i++) {

        // Invested capital over the years (works fine)
        investedCapital = (investedCapitalArray[i - 1]) +
            (frequency * additionalDeposit);
        investedCapitalArray.push(investedCapital);

        //  imple interest over the years (works fine)
        simpleInterest = simpleInterestArray[i - 1] +
            ((firstYearInvestment + (frequency * additionalDeposit) * i) * interest);
        simpleInterestArray.push(simpleInterest);

        // compound interest over the years (correct results)
        compoundInterest += (((simpleInterestArray[i - 1] + compoundInterest) * (interest)));
        compoundInterestArray.push(compoundInterest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the paranthesis you should use `(investedCapitalArray[i - 1] + compoundInterestArray[i - 1]) * (1 + 0.07)`. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this change makes it even worse.

Comment: I think i misunderstood the problem. Are you trying to store the compound interest amount or the capital plus the compound interest amount? If it is only the compound interest amount then re-adding it with the initial capital amount is not required which you have done.

Comment: I need to store the accumulated compund interest only. (the two other calculations are fine). So I have problem with this line:   
    compoundInterestArray.push( compoundInterestArray[i-1] + (parseInt(investedCapitalArray[i-1] + simpleInterestArray[i-1]) * ( rateNumberic.getNumber() / 100))  );

Comment: You need to remove the `compoundInterestArray[i - 1]` because you are adding the previous years compound interest with this years interest which is wrong so just keep the part which i had posted and that should do it.

Comment: I think there is another issue with this solution we cannot use the `capitalInvestmentArray` for the compound interest calculation becuase the initial capital will increase every year as the interest will be added to it so we will another array to store the newly computed capital and then calculate the CI amount on that computed captial investment amount.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with unboxing the object. Try this:

```
compoundInterestArray.push( compoundInterestArray[i-1] + (parseInt(investedCapitalArray[i-1]) + parseInt(simpleInterestArray[i-1])) * ( rateNumberic.getNumber() / 100))  );
```

Comment: Thank you, but there was an extra paranthesis in your code, after removing that it still does work properly :( Still trying to think what it could be